# Change android ListView item fore color

Tags: android, listview, colors

I want to change the color of my ListView items (populated with Async class) depending on a variable. So, I have this

```
public class Search extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    boolean blue = false;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        List<String> Items = Arrays.asList(res.getStringArray(R.array.Items));
        for (String it : Items) {
            if (it.contains("blue")) { blue = true; } else { blue = false; }    
            publishProgress(it);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
        ((ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
        // Change the color of the current item depending on "blue"
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `getView` in a custom adapter, and provide your own custom View.

Comment: Inside which class, or where?

Comment: extend BaseAdapter or some other adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you may add elements to your array adapter. However there are several issues to take care of:

1. pass in an ArrayList or anything else where you can actually call `add` on
2. don't forget to call setNotifyOnChange(true);

So in general that should do it. However, I am not really sure I understand why and what you are doing with the AsyncTask that adds the items...

Why don't you just add them when you create the ListView? Is there something I missed?

Comment: I removed some unnecessary code for this issue. The AsynkTask also filters the items, but I didn't include that code